# Install4J Install into different directory selected but ignored on install

Tags: install4j

On windows using Install4j 5.1.12,

This is the scenario:
1). Successfully Install version 1 of app1 in directory v1
2). Try install of version 2 of app1 ( same APPid as above) but check  'No, install into a different directory'.
so that, version 1 remain where it is installed. But, version2 goes to a new directory 'v2'.

Expected : after step 2, I was expecting a new directory called 'v2' created and version2 of the app installed in the new dir 'v2'.

Actual: After step 2, version2 installed on top of version1 in dir 'v1' and no dir 'v2' created.

This used to work in old versions of our app installer. I compared it to the sample apps 'hello' of Install4j 5.1.12. Installer/update options has 'Regular Installer'/ Detect previous installation dir selected in the same way as the 'sample' apps.

Wondering what else to check .

Thanks , let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: It seems that there is code in your project that reset the installation directory. The file .install4lj/.installation.log in the installation directory will help you find out where that occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ingo, yes there was a condition the was using a wrong context setting ,
instead of :
context.getBooleanVariable("sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation") == true

it was :
context.isUpdateInstallation() == true

Thanks for the hint and further support.
-G